# syslog configuration - repeated alert?

Tags: solaris, syslog

i am using solaris 10 and saw this line in `/etc/syslog.conf`

```
*.err;kern.debug;daemon.notice;mail.crit;auth.debug;local2.notice       /var/adm/messages
```

Does it mean that, if I have a **auth.err**, the error message will appear in my `/var/adm/message` twice due to the:

```
*.err  
auth.debug
```

If let's say I also have another line which is:

```
*.emerg  *
*.err;kern.debug;daemon.notice;mail.crit;auth.debug;local2.notice       /var/adm/messages
```

Does it mean that, if i have a **kernel.emerg**,  it will log twice to `/var/adm/messages` due to

```
 *.emerg  *   and
kern.debug  /var/adm/messages
```

?

=======

Added on

```
auth.notice         ifdef(`LOGHOST', /var/log/authlog, @loghost)
```

- how does syslog check if this machine is a loghost or not ?
  by checking the /etc/hosts for the "loghost" aliase and see if it matches the IP of the machine  ?
- I have syslog.conf without ifdef and it still works, is ifdef necessary or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are mostly defining filters applied at runtime to each message, so in reality, you are not supposed to have duplicated messages in the same destination/file.

> Multiple selectors may be specified for a single action using the
>   semicolon ('';'') separator. Remember that each selector in the
>   selector field is capable to overwrite the preceding ones.

You can and do get however, the same message sent to different files, including the console.

In the case of

```
*.emerg *
```

Which is shorthand to all users in syslog, it will to all users.

> Everyone logged on
>
> Emergency messages often go to all users currently online to notify
>   them that something strange is happening with the system. To specify
>   this wall(1)-feature use an asterisk (''*'').

So indeed, in a kernel.emerg,  will  both send it to all users, and to /var/adm/messages at the same; however it will be only one line in /var/adm/messages.

> The behavior of the original BSD syslogd is that all messages of the
>   specified priority and higher are logged according to the given
>   action.

Quotes taken from `syslog.conf` man page:

[syslog.conf(5) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf)

as for the ifdef, taking as an example:

```
auth.notice         ifdef(`LOGHOST', /var/log/authlog, @loghost)
```

If LOGHOST is defined (i.e. this syslog is a LOGHOST, it will send the log/message to /var/log/authlog, otherwise will sent it to @loghost.

As for ifdef it is not a requirement, and as for LOGHOST, according to [this page](http://www.softpanorama.org/Logs/loghost_server_and_remote_syslog.shtml) it is the name of the machine taken from the file /etc/hosts (or possibly DNS, only testing)

> To edit /etc/hosts  (./inet/hosts) and add one or several lines that
>   defines IP address for loghost (Name is arbitrary, and if several
>   remote hosts are defined you can use any name you wish)

Comment: oddly enough, I only find a link to filters for  syslog-ng and rsyslog in google...https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-filters.html

Comment: I think the destination * means to all users, and not all destination ?

Comment: Exactly, let me correct it.

Comment: thanks - do you mind if you explain what does ifdef means in a syslog config ? try googling but cant find much explaination

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Comment: thanks !  -  I have edited my original question, would truely appreciate if you can take a look if possible

Comment: indeed, changed the answer again. Let me check syslog man pages, now I got confused.

Comment: Yep, confirmed.

Comment: I think you have mistaken, what I meant is I added some questions to my original post, , would appreciate if you can take a look at them ;) thanks

Comment: The original intention of Linux&Unix is not to keep moving the goalpost of the questions. No, ifdef is not a requirement, I do not have it also. I have added to the answer.